# Best solution to accumulate Spark Streaming DStream

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, dstream

I'm looking for the best solution to accumulate the last N number of messages in a Spark DStream. I'd also like to specify the number of messages to retain.

For example, given the following stream, I'd like to retain the last 3 elements:

```
Iteration  New message  Downstream
1          A            [A]
2          B            [A, B]
3          C            [A, B, C]
4          D            [B, C, D]
```

So far I'm looking at the following methods on DStream:

1. updateStateByKey: given that all messages have the same key I can do this. But looks a bit odd why this needs to know about the key at all.
2. mapWithState: the API in Scala is just too tedious for such a simple thing
3. window: doesn't seem to do this job, also it needs a time value for windowing instead of the last number of elements
4. Accumulators: not really used yet [Accumulators in Spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/streaming-programming-guide.html#accumulators-and-broadcast-variables)

What's the best solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

`mapWithState` is exactly what you need, and it's definitely not too tedious:

```
case class Message(x: String)
def statefulTransformation(key: Int,
                           value: Option[Message],
                           state: State[mutable.MutableList[Message]]): Option[Message] = {
  def updateState(value: Message): Message = {
    val updatedList =
      state
        .getOption()
        .map(list => if (list.size > 3) list.drop(1) :+ value else list :+ value)
      .getOrElse(mutable.MutableList(value))

    state.update(updatedList)
    value
  }

  value.map(updateState)
}
```

And now all you need is:

```
val stateSpec = StateSpec.function(statefulTransformation _)
dStream.mapWithState(stateSpec)
```

Side note - I used `mutable.MutableList` for the constant time append.